# How can I add items from an ArrayList to a TableCloum using an FXML file? ~JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I wonder if there is an option to add the `Sting name = "xy"` to a `TableColumn` from a `TableView`.

My program updates the `ArrayList` frequently, so I want to delete all the items out of the `TableColumn` and add the String variable name to the `TableCloumn`.

I set up my program with JavaFX Scene Builder.
My table has the fixed id: cardsTable and my Colum had the id cardsColumn.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you add more information about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can not add variables to the table in fxml, you can only add columns and their names.

```
<TableView fx:id="table">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn fx:id="test1" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Test1" />
      <TableColumn fx:id="test2" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Test2" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="test3" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Test3" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="test4" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Test4" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="test5" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Test5" />
    </columns>
  </TableView>
```